# Image backup with two Macs

Tags: networking, mac, backup, disk-image

My setup is as follows:

- iMac + Ext. HD in the living room
- A MacBook

I want to create a regular weekly backup flow, that will create an image file for the MacBook (the entire disk image), and save it to the ext. HD on the iMac, meaning -- connect via local network and save the file.

What's the best practice/application for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Is the external HD bootable? Once a week I'd just boot the MacBook from the exteranl HD and run [CCC](http://www.bombich.com/) or [SuperDuper!](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) .. to create a bootable image and keep it on that same external HD....Not sure if I'd push the entire disk image over a network like that....If you were just incrementaly backing up files in your home directory only , that might make more sense over the network...

Comment: SuperDuper! can do incremental backups, if you pay for it.  I would create the initial backup with the drive connected locally, and then try incremental backups over the network.  Only if that wasn't fast enough, would I bother moving the disk every week.

Comment: I run an incremental backup with SuperDuper every day at 5pm to an external drive. I used to do the same to an NAS over WiFi. The incremental backups don't take long at all.